# Play INDIE 103.1 stream in Chrome Radio Player extension

Tags: audio-streaming, chromium, tcpdump, internet-radio

Can anyone help me to find the streaming URL of the [INDIE 103.1 online player](http://player.streamtheworld.com/liveplayer.php?callsign=KDLDFM)? I'm looking for a way to play the stream directly through the [Chrome Radio Player extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgjdhckebbdoobhniheihpdogeoeelbn). I already tried fiddling with tcpdump:

```
tcpdump -i wlan0 -nn -s0 -A -l|grep --line-buffered "XEDAFM?streamtheworld_user" -A 2|grep --line-buffered "Host: \|GET "
```

and found requests of the form

```
.UY&.X.{GET /KDLDFMAAC?streamtheworld_user=1&nobuf=1315831486041 HTTP/1.1
Host: 208.80.54.96
```

However, trying to play `http://208.80.54.96//KDLDFMAAC?streamtheworld_user=1&nobuf=1315831486041` doesn't seem to work.

---

**EDIT 1:**

I found that the URL `http://208.80.52.108/KDLDFMCMP3` plays the stream when accessed directly via Chromium. However, the Radio Player extension doesn't play the stream. All I can see from terminal is

```
New Stream Requested - chrome-extension://hgjdhckebbdoobhniheihpdogeoeelbn/background.html
Entering destroy stream reason = 0 for chrome-extension://hgjdhckebbdoobhniheihpdogeoeelbn/background.html
Sending SetProgressText to connection 0x56f95a0
URL Notify url = 'chrome-extension://hgjdhckebbdoobhniheihpdogeoeelbn/background.html'
reason = 0
chrome-extension://hgjdhckebbdoobhniheihpdogeoeelbn/background.html
/home/jm/.cache/gnome-mplayer/plugin/gecko-mediaplayerdikdwn
/control/18890
New Stream Requested - http://208.80.52.108/KDLDFMCMP3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look here: [Indie 103.1 FM lives again on the web](http://sketchstudios.net/wordpress/2009/01/indie-1031-fm-lives-again-on-the-web/)

Using this URL "**http://provisioning.streamtheworld.com/pls/KDLDFM.pls**" you can run Indie 103.1 in the Chrome Radio Player extension.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually uninstalled the radio player extension some time ago and now I can't find it in the Chrome Web Store anymore. Looks like the author removed it. So, unfortunately, I'm unable to check that link in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone finds this question (like I did through Google), Indie 103.1 is now streaming at

http://stream.abacast.net/playlist/entravision-indieaac-ibc2.m3u

I listen through Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 1):

If your player prefers MP3 to AAC, http://stream.abacast.net/playlist/entravision-indiemp3-ibc2.m3u also works.